# Is heaven (savarglok) a physical thing or it is just metaphorical

Tags: heaven

There are many scholar who say that heaven is physical but there many scholar that says heaven is metaphorical. Which is correct.

> |AV 12.3.26||
> From heaven they come, they visit earth, and rising from earth unite themselves with air's mid-region, Purified, excellent, they with shine in beauty. Thus may they lead us to the world of Svarga.

> 18 Thus speak these Gods to thee, O son of Iḷā: As death hath verily got thee for his subject, Thy sons shall serve the Gods with their oblation, and thou, moreover, shalt rejoice in Svarga.RV 10.95.18

These verse indicate that the savarglok is physical.
So why many scholar say it is metaphor.

Comment: They may be saying because they’ve not experienced it.

Comment: It is not material in the sense of the material world as we know it. Upon death, it is the fine body, the subtle body that goes to the heavens. See here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body

Comment: You have to define physical first.

Comment: [Related] [What are the vedic references for swarga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24842/93)

Comment: @Wikash_  it is physical( relating to things perceived through the senses as opposed to the mind; tangible or concrete) or metaphorical